# Build python - R - python pipeline

Tags: python, r

I am trying to build a pipeline which has 3 modules. The first module uses a python script to generate the outstanding product names, the second module uses the product name as an input in R script to fetch the data from database, perform transformations and stores the data in the csv. The third module uses python again to read the data from the csv and generates a report.

There are business reasons why the modules are using different scripts. The challenge that I am facing is integrating these modules. Is there a way where I can trigger R script through python once the product name is generated in the first module. I checked few answers available online but most of them talk about triggering a simple r function instead of series of instructions provided in R Script. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Please let me know if you need more details. I am using Windows server to build such pipeline.

Thanks,
Triki

Comment: Have you looked as using [rpy2](https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/)? It is a package that allows for use of python code in r and r code in python. You could set up a main handler (in either language) that calls each script. Alternatively, use PowerShell or Batch to call python files and r files.

Comment: Presumably you can invoke a system command that runs `Rscript` with your script, potentially with arguments.

Comment: Hey Brydenr, yes I looked through the rpy2 package. It doesn't explain how to trigger the entire R script at once through python. I am digging deep into it now. Regarding the batch calls, can you suggest a good reference material ?

Comment: Thanks Axeman and Brydenr. Your suggestions were helpful

Answer (score 0):

After various trials, I was able to accomplish what I wanted in the following way.

Defined the required functions in the R script and triggered the R script through a batch file as following from the python

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(["path\to\the\batchfile.bat", arg1 arg2]).wait()
```

The batch file has the following

```
RScript "C:\Users\test.R" %1 %2  >> "C:\Users\test_output.txt"
```

test.R has the following (For example)

```
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly=TRUE)
a = args[1]
b = args[2]
add<- function(a,b) {
      return (a+b)
}

add(a,b)
```

I hope this helps some one who are looking to integrate the R script inside python. We can use Rpy2 package too. But, I faced issue while installing it.

Thanks,
Triki